# Работа с массивами символов (char)

Tags: c, char

**Помогите реализовать следующее задание:**
Дано предложение. Распечатать из него все слова, перед которыми непосредственно находится буква `ch` в одном слове. Буква `ch` вводится с клавиатуры. `ch` — это название переменной, которая тоже должна быть (char), и её мы инициализируем, вводом буквы.

Есть код, но там бред полный, и пока ничего не выходит. Пробовал через различные функции, проверки и т.п... Строго не судите, ЯЗЫК С для меня это ещё начало...

```c
char str[100];
    printf(" строку -> "); fgets(str, 100, stdin); 
    puts(str);
 
    char ch[100];   printf(" букву -> "); fgets(ch, 100, stdin);
 
    do {   
        printf(" "); puts(str);
    } while (strcmp(str, ch) != 0);

char str[100];
printf(" строку -> "); fgets(str, 100, stdin); 
puts(str); 
  
char ch[100]; printf(" букву ->"); scanf("%s", ch); 
for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) { 
  if (str[i] == ch) {
    //printf("%s", str[i]);
  }
  printf("%s", str[i]); 
}
```

Comment: Для начала вы должны определить для себя, что такое слово? Т.е. какие символы могут входить в слово, а какие нет (и являются разделителями между словами). Далее, вашей задачей будет нахождение слов. Судя по условию задачи, вам надо будет проверить, содержит ли только что найденное слово заданную букву и в таком случае напечатать следующее слово (не забудьте проверить и его на наличие этой буквы). Далее в цикле. / Совет -- попробуйте разбить код программы на функции, которые выполняют элементарные шаги алгоритма.

Comment: Я бы рекомендовал начать с русского. Тем не менее, попробуйте начать с простого, а именно словами опишите то, как вы собираетесь решать задачу.